# Graphql request response is undefined from react, but good at playground

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

> when I'm trying to log "res" in signup Mutation from - "Playground"
> it's good. It gave me the response object but when I try it from the
> client it shows me "undefined" and
> A beautiful error in the client - res.cookie is undefined

**server-side code**

// app.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PRODUCTION") {
    require("dotenv").config();
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE_URI).then(success => {
    console.log("Connected successfully....")
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.messege);
    console.log("Fail to connect....")
})


app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql' || 'http://localhost:5000'
}));

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));


module.exports = app;
```

//server.js file

```
const app = require("./app")
const { ApolloServer, } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { execute, subscribe } = require("graphql")
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
const { SubscriptionServer } = require("subscriptions-transport-ws")
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const typeDefs = require('./Graphql/TypeDefs/app');
const resolvers = require('./Graphql/Resolvers/app');
const { PubSub } = require('graphql-subscriptions');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const pubsub = new PubSub();

(async () => {
    try {
        const getUser = token => {
            try {
                if (token) {
                    return jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
                }
                return null
            } catch (err) {
                return null
            }
        }

        const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers, });
        const subscriptionServer = new SubscriptionServer(
            { schema, execute, subscribe, },
            { server: httpServer, path: '/graphql' }
        );

        const server = new ApolloServer({
            schema,
            context: ({ req, res }) => {
                const token = req.cookies.token || ""
                const user = getUser(token)
                return { req, res, pubsub, user }
            },
            plugins: [{
                async serverWillStart() {
                    return {
                        async drainServer() {
                            subscriptionServer.close();
                        }
                    };
                }
            }],


        })

        await server.start()
        server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })
        httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log('server is running on port ', + PORT))

    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message)
    }
})()
```

**Mutation**

Mutation: {

```
    signUp: async (_, { input }, { res }) => {
        console.log(res)
        const { email, password, firstName, lastName } = input
        try {
            const isExixt = await User.findOne({ email })
            if (isExixt) {
                return {
                    success: true,
                    message: `user exist! try to login`
                }
            } else {
                const newUser = await User.create({
                    email, password, firstName, lastName
                })
                const token = jwt.sign({ user: newUser }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, {
                    expiresIn: '7d'
                })
                res.cookie('token', token, {
                    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 604800000),
                    httpOnly: true
                })
                return { success: true, token, user: newUser }
            }

        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message)
        }
    }

}
```

**client**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import "./style/app.css"
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { WebSocketLink } from "@apollo/client/link/ws"
import Context from './components/Provider/Context'

const link = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: 'ws://localhost:5000/graphql',
  options: {
    reconnect: true
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: `http://localhost:5000/graphql`,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link,
  credentials: 'same-origin',
 //credentials: 'include',

})


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <Router>
      <ApolloProvider client={client} >
        <Context>
          <App />
        </Context>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

// also tried proxy:http://localhost:5000/graphql

Comment: I found the problem, but I couldn't solve this, the problem on **httpServer** , the subscription is working on httpServer.listen() but the response from client is undefined, at the same time  **app.listen()** is working on the client but not in subscription, so what can I do now??